# Math from markdown to latex using pandoc and pandown in sublime text

Tags: latex, markdown, sublimetext, pandoc

so I'm using sublime text to write in markdown and then using pandoc (via pandown) to typeset my markdown for printing using latex (TexLive on OS X). This is working excellently except when it comes to math.

So my markdown input is:

```
This is a document in Markdown

This is some $45+\sigma = \kappa$ inline math

This is the end of the document in markdown
```

And then the output pandoc gives me is (with all the preamble removed):

```
\begin{document}

This is a document in Markdown

This is some \(45+\sigma = \kappa\) inline math

This is the end of the document in markdown

\end{document}
```

Settings wise I'm using the default pandown settings found [here](https://github.com/phyllisstein/Pandown/blob/master/Pandown.sublime-settings) with the only other pandown settings being bib related (which all works fine).

```
{
    "bibliography": ".../library.bib",
    "csl": ".../harvard.csl",
}
```

Any ideas? I'm assuming its something super simple that I'm missing, but I can't work out what it is!!

Comment: What's wrong with the output?

Comment: Jesus I'm an idiot...nothing, it compiles fine.

I was just expecting it to be in $...$ format, as thats all ever use.

Thanks.